# Regex find 'a' or 'an' in sentence in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I am beginner in `Regex`. I thought I would complete this without help but couldn't.

I want to find `article word` pair from following sentence(where **article must be A or An**):

```
This is a sentence. An egg is a word. A gee another word. 
Last line is a word. Ocean is very big.
```

I used this regex pattern:

```
/[(An)|(an)|a|A]\s+\w+[\s|.]/
```

Captured pairs are:

```
'a sentence.', 'n egg ', 'a word.', 'A gee ', 'a word.', 'n is '.
```

Above pattern couldn't capture `An egg` fully. However, more **strangely** it captured `'n is '` in `Ocean is`.

What could be correct pattern to extract it?

Comment: You need to include word boundaries around those match strings. See `\b` in the regex documentation. E.g., something like `/\b[(An)|(an)|a|A]\b\s+\w+[\s|.]/

Comment: The reason you get `n egg ` and `n is ` is you are mixing up [character classes (`[...]`)](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Classes) and [alternation (`|`)](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Alternation). They are similar in some ways, but a character class will only match a single character – the `[(An)|(an)|a|A]` part of your regex is basically the same as `[Aan]` or `(A|a|n)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = 'This is a sentence. An egg is a word. A gee another word.\nLast line is a word. Ocean is very big.'
s.scan /(?<=\A|\s)[Aa]n?\s+[A-Za-z]+/m
# => [
#   [0] "a sentence",
#   [1] "An egg",
#   [2] "a word",
#   [3] "A gee",
#   [4] "a word"
# ]
```

Here we go: `/(?<=\A|\s)[Aa]n?\s+[A-Za-z]+/m`

First is a lookbehind for not matching “an is” in “Ocean is.” Then we look for A (maybe capital), possibly followed by “n”, then spaces and word itself. Final `m` states for multiline.

To avoid using lookbehind, one may change the regexp to:

```
/\b[Aa]n?\s+[A-Za-z]+/m
```

**UPD** One should avoid using `\w` here since `\w` matches `[A-Za-z0-9_]` note especially the underscore.

Comment: Is lookbehind slow? This solve my purpose /\b[Aa]n?\s+\w+/m. Any reason you opt for [A-Za-z]+ ?

Comment: Here it does not matter at all.

Comment: What if my word contains underscore :) ?

Comment: `\w` matches underscore, see update. Use `\w` if you’re OK with digits *and* underscore, use ranges otherwise.

Comment: Agreed to use [A-Za-z] instead of \w. :)

Comment: @ram even better, use `/\p{Alpha}/` to match things like `é`, `ü` etc.

Comment: The use of a negative lookbehind and character ranges for the second word smell bad to me. Ruby's regexps support more semantic constructions.

Comment: @Max @matt  There was clearly stated: OP is interested in *english articles*. Therefore we have to assume it’s English language. That’s why there are ranges instead of `\p{L}`. There is nothing more semantic in Ruby regexps (according to the fact we know the semantics is English) than ranges in such a case. Apologies whether your opinion differs.

Comment: @mudasobwa Yes, it was rather naïve of me. Maybe I'll go to a café and have a frappé whilst I think it over. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Add a word boundary:

```
/\b(an?)\s+\w+/i
```

**Edit:** (`n` mustn't be capital)

```
/\b([aA]n?)\s+\w+/
```

Comment: “a” might be capital, not “n”.

Comment: This could also match "aN" or "AN", but it is the most elegant/simple solution if that doesn't matter.

Comment: @mudasobwa the `i` ant the end makes it case insensitive.

Comment: @p11y Thanks for the tip. I would repeat: ‘“a” might be capital, **not “n”**’

Comment: @mudasobwa sorry, I read it the wrong way :) You could still do `/\b[Aa]n?)\s+\w+/`

Answer (score 1):

Try simplifying to `\b(An|an|a|A) \w+\b`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a very simple pattern, along with `scan` to find all occurrences:

```
sentence = <<EOT
This is a sentence. An egg is a word. A gee another word. 
Last line is a word. Ocean is very big.
EOT

sentence.scan(/\b an? \s+ [a-z]+/imx)
# => ["a sentence", "An egg", "a word", "A gee", "a word"]
```

I'm using the `x` flag to improve the readability of the pattern.

The pattern breaks down to:

- `\b`: a word-boundary so only `"a"` or `"an"` match. (It's case insensitive.)
- `an?`: matches `"a"` or `"an"`.
- `\s+`: matches one or more white-spaces.
- `[a-z]+`: matches consecutive runs of letters only. This is significant because any pattern using the `\w` character-class would also match 0..9 and "_" (underscore). Your sample doesn't contain those, but any text containing those characters would be likely to give you bad results.
- The `i` flag means ignore case. The `m` flag means to treat the text as a single line of text. Normally line-ends are more significant. `x` means that white-spaces in the pattern are not significant, requiring `\s` to mark where they should be.

If you want the trailing punctuation or space, add `.` to the end of the pattern:

```
sentence.scan(/\b an? \s+ [a-z]+ ./imx)
# => ["a sentence.", "An egg ", "a word.", "A gee ", "a word."]
```